# How to load a csv file to an ArrayList <Object Type> while the other array is of strings?

Tags: java, csv

The method below is used to load the CSV file into an array of Strings, I want to store the elements in the created array into an `ArrayList<Attack>` where Attack is an abstract class. I have about 3 CSV files each should be loaded into an `ArrayList` of the other class types, so how would I implement it ?

```
private static String[] loadCSV(String filePath) throws IOException
{
    String currentLine="";
    String[] tmp = null;
    FileReader fileReader=new FileReader(filePath);
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(fileReader);
    while((currentLine=br.readLine())!=null) 
         tmp = currentLine.split(",");

    return tmp; 
}
```

Comment: You can not instantiate abstract classes. You can create something like `Attack.valueOf(String attackType){...}` (hint: you probably want to consider enums) to map your strings to concrete types.

Comment: @Raedwald Maybe because I can't and I need help ?

Comment: Everyone thinks parsing CSV is trivial, but you'll save yourself a lot of surprise and pain by just using an existing lib. This explains it all: http://demeranville.com/how-not-to-parse-csv-using-java/

Comment: A dirty approach: Use a database and import cvs into that database. Write queries to do whatever you like in your little java program.

Comment: How does that help the OP either with CSV parsing or with POJO mapping??

Comment: By using a database, you do not have to worry about parsing CVS. Many database handle that very well. You could incorporate an ORM and it saves time doing data mapping.

Comment: Talk about using a sledgehammer to crack a nut. Strictly speaking Jackson is an ORM, but wiring up Hibernate and a DBMS to tackle this question seems crazily excessive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in the comments, CSV-parsing is [far from trivial](http://demeranville.com/how-not-to-parse-csv-using-java/), and should be delegated to a proven library.

This problem (reading, parsing, and data-binding) seems a perfect fit for [Jackson's CSV Data format module](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-csv):

> Jackson data format module for reading and writing CSV encoded data,
>   either as "raw" data (sequence of String arrays), or via data binding
>   to/from Java Objects (POJOs).

There are lots of examples, so rather than pick one, I'd suggest reading the article, considering the possibilities, and deciding which works best for your needs.

Comment: Thank you so much, you are a life saver !!

Comment: I agree. But I would suggestion to have a look here:  http://csvjdbc.sourceforge.net/

Comment: It's good to know about, but OP wanted data binding, which Jackson delivers in one go. I don't think he should have to install a database and use the JDBC API, then still have to either deserialize by hand or add an ORM layer too. As I said in the comments, that's sledgehammer vs nut.